# Using a Conditional Statement in AngularUI's Collapse Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can I place a conditional statement into the `collapse` directive for AngularUI?

I have the following setup, which has 3 radio-style buttons:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="radioPurpose" btn-radio="'meeting'">Meeting</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="radioPurpose" btn-radio="'tour'">Tour</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" ng-model="radioPurpose" btn-radio="'other'">Other...</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="controls controls-row">
  <textarea class="span6" placeholder="Why are you here?" ng-model="textPurpose" collapse="{{ radioPurpose == 'other' }}"></textarea>
</div>
```

I would like `textarea` to show/hide according to the value of the `radioPurpose` buttons.  I know the statement is evaluating to `true` at the appropriate time, but the directive always shows the `textarea`.

Comment: I haven't used AngularUI, but I'm guessing `collapse` expects an expression. Remove the curly braces: `collapse="radioPurpose == 'other'"`

Comment: Gah, I swear I had tried that... but I suppose not.  Working now!

Comment: p.s., if you put this in answer form I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied answer from comment:

I haven't used AngularUI, but I'm guessing `collapse` expects an expression. Remove the curly braces: `collapse="radioPurpose == 'other'"`

Answer (score 0):

Collapse is actually not the best way of doing a simple show/hide. A collapsed item has its height set to 0, rather than being set to `display: none`; it might not always have the effect you're expecting.  I would suggest instead using `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

Comment: In my case I'm also looking for the animation associated with the collapse.  It is a simple app on a controlled platform in a controlled environment, so the solution is suitable for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you solved it, and so did I and can share my JSFiddle; [Toggle Collapse with Radiobuttons](http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/4kkpm/).

However, I see what S McCrohan mean, since I got a problem in my app. The collapse for the table did not work fully in my app first, since it collapsed but left the top row visible. It seems to require that you separate the divs, i.e. a div with collapse and a div with span# class, like following...:

```
    <!-- START CHART AREA -->
    <div collapse="chartCollapsed">
       <div class="span12 well well-small">
          <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END CHART AREA -->
    <!-- START TABLE AREA -->
    <div collapse="tableCollapsed">
       <div class="span12">
                               <!-- TABLE OMITTED -->
       </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TABLE AREA -->
```